# Breeze.js - Unable to resolve an expression for: 1367380800000 on entityType: Order:#Zza.Data

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I am following the course on Pluralsight at [Building Data-Centric Single Page Apps with Breeze](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-single-page-applications-breeze). The code here was using 1.4.2 version of Breeze and was running on Web API v1 and EF 5.  I upgraded the solution to EF 6, Web API v2 and Breeze v1.5.1 with some success.  I was able to get a basic query up and running as well as a simple predicate running as shown below:

```
var productsWithBacon = function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Products").where("Description", "contains", "bacon");
    app.em.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        products(data.results);
    })
    .fail(errorLoading);
};
```

The problem occurs when I try to do a complex predicate as seen here.

```
var ordersGreaterThan100InMay = function () {
    clearCollections();
    var gteMay1 = new breeze.Predicate("OrderDate", ">=", moment("2013-05-01"));
    var lteMay31 = new breeze.Predicate("OrderDate", "<=", moment("2013-05-31"));
    var gt100 = new breeze.Predicate("ItemsTotal", ">=", 100);
    var predicate = breeze.Predicate.and(gteMay1, lteMay31, gt100);
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Orders").where(predicate).expand("Customer");
    app.em.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {
            orders(data.results);
        })
        .fail(errorLoading);
};
```

When executing, I get the error as seen in the title

```
Unable to resolve an expression for: 1367380800000 on entityType: Order:#Zza.Data
```

Originally, the code (as described in the course) was to use a line like:

```
var gt100 = new breeze.Predicate("ItemsTotal", "greaterThanOrEqual", 100);
```

This cause an error of:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve predicate after the phrase: 'ItemsTotal' for operator: 'greaterThanOrEqual'  and value: '100'
```

but that was resolved by changing to ">=".

What is causing the expression error though?

Comment: Does breeze understood how to handle Moment objects?  Shouldn't the OrderDate predicates be using moment's toDate function?  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/
For example:
`var gteMay1 = new breeze.Predicate("OrderDate", ">=", moment("2013-05-01").toDate());`

Comment: I can give that a try, but the course (using an older version of breeze and Web.API/EF works with the moment object just fine.  Maybe it was changed in the newer versions.

Comment: wow didn't know that- let me know what you find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter in my post above was correct.

Apparently, either the update of Moment.js (Original version from course was 2.2.1) to the most recent version (2.8.2 as of this writing) may have changed something.  I don't know if it was moment not returning an actual date object or something in Breeze that changed, but the following code does work.

```
var ordersGreaterThan100InMay = function () {
    clearCollections();
    var gteMay1 = breeze.Predicate.create("OrderDate", ">=", moment("2013-05-01").toDate());
    var lteMay31 = breeze.Predicate.create("OrderDate", "<=", moment("2013-05-31").toDate());
    var gt100 = breeze.Predicate.create("ItemsTotal", ">=", 100);
    var predicate = breeze.Predicate.and(gteMay1, lteMay31, gt100);
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Orders").where(predicate);
    app.em.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {
            orders(data.results);
        })
        .fail(errorLoading);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am perplexed by the code you're showing me. I see it, plain as day, at the 1'04" mark of the "[Breeze Query Basics: Demo: Complex Filter Criteria](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=brian-noyes&name=building-single-page-applications-breeze-m3&mode=live&clip=6&course=building-single-page-applications-breeze)" clip.

To my knowledge **"greaterThanOrEqual" has never been a supported predicate comparison operator**. I just searched the history of breeze on github back as far as I can go and I can't find it.

Similarly, AFAIK, **a `moment` date has never been a valid predicate comparison value**.

I'm flummoxed. I want to be wrong. I want to have reason to apologize for having broken your application with a change to breeze. I just can't find where this ever could have worked. I will ask the course author about how he made it work.

FWIW, you have figured out the proper syntax for today's breeze.

#### Update 13 December 2014

With help from course author, Brian Noyes, I found the regressions you discovered. Although both the use of `FilterQueryOp` symbol names (e.g., "greaterThanOrEqual") as operation names and the use of [moment.js dates](http://momentjs.com/) as predicate comparison values were never documented, they clearly did work back when the course was produced (around Breeze v.1.4.2). I decided we should support what Brian shows in his course and treat these as *bona fide* regressions. They will will be supported in the next breeze release (v.1.5.3?)

N.B.: Moment.js dates will only work as predicate comparison values. Moment.js is not yet supported as an alternate Date type anywhere else in Breeze. I'd like to see that happen but it isn't now and we have not scheduled time to add that support.

Comment: See Brian's comment. Yup ... it used to work. I think he took advantage of ***undocumented*** behaviors. Will now consider whether these behaviors should become **documented features** or whether they should be bugs. I'm leaning toward the former but no promises. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the course in question here. Not sure what to say since I agree with Ward - that has never been a supported operator as a string. It is the name of one of the FilterQueryOp enum values, so I must have made an error putting in that code where I copy/pasted the enum value name as a string instead of using it as an enumerated value. Embarrased that I shipped non-functional code in the course, will get that corrected next time I update the course.

Comment: Do you agree about the moment value as well?  What's odder is that the code shipped actually worked. Something from one version of either moment or breeze made it so it didn't. Glad it al, works now, just find it a little confusing.

Comment: And yet I just went back and ran my own sample and it works fine. Didn't think I would ship broken code as part of a course. Will have to follow up with the Breeze folks to try to understand why.

Comment: You're right. It used to work. You were taking advantage of what I think were ***undocumented*** behaviors that are no longer present in recent Breeze releases. I am exploring what those were and considering if we should restore them as **documented** features. More soon.